# How does dynamic object access work in V8?

Tags: javascript, v8

I was surprised to find out that JavaScript objects [are not in fact hash maps under the hood, instead they are more similar to structs](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties). From what I understand, getting and setting properties on an object is fast because the memory location of the value is at a fixed offset, as it would be in a struct or a class. What I don’t understand is how the syntax maps to that fixed offset. Ie what happens when the compiler sees `obj.a` or `obj[‘a’]`. Is that syntax transformed into an integer offset at run time or compile time or JIT? I guess what I’m trying to understand is how can it transform the incoming string ‘a’ into an integer index efficiently without doing something like `index = hash(‘a’) % objectLength`.

Maybe the gap in my knowledge is I don’t fully get how structs work at the compiler level.

Comment: It can't be at "compile time" because properties can be added (and removed!) during execution.

Comment: "*JavaScript objects*" - notice you're looking at one particular engine only. Others might work similarly, or completely different.

Comment: From the linked article: "*To get from the name of the property to the actual position in the properties store, we have to consult the descriptor array on the HiddenClass, as we've outlined before.*" - it's really just a linear search through the descriptor array, which isn't that big. This then gets spiced up by inline caches.

Comment: @scott well not quite, you could compile it for some certain object structure with certain properties, then when the object structure changes recompile.

Comment: @JonasWilms: That would make the concept of "compile time" awfully mushy.

Comment: The concept of "compile time" is a bit blurry here anyway since javascript is an interpreted language but it's especially fuzzy to me as I'm not a compiler guy. It would be useful if you can provide more insight into the relevant stages of the v8 engine. @ScottHunter

Comment: To be clear: if I had answered "it happens at compile time", you wouldn't know what I meant?  Kind of a hallmark of a bad question, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

> JavaScript objects are not in fact hash maps under the hood, instead they are more similar to structs.

For the record, Bergi correctly points out that this is true in one engine, and even in that engine not always. JavaScript engines have a lot of freedom in how exactly to represent objects internally, and they do make use of that freedom.

> What I don’t understand is how the syntax maps to that fixed offset. Ie what happens when the compiler sees obj.a or obj[‘a’]. Is that syntax transformed into an integer offset at run time or compile time or JIT?

The system is based on caching, and "hidden classes" (sometimes referred to as "object shapes" or "[object] shape descriptors").

When you have an object `obj = {a: 42, b: "hello", c: null}`, it will have a hidden class (let's call it `hiddenClassA` that lists all properties and their offsets, e.g. "property `a` is stored at offset 12".

The first execution of a function containing a property load like `obj.a` will be using unoptimized code. This code will have to inspect the object, find `a` in its hidden class' list of properties, retrieve the correct offset from there, and then read from that offset in the object to get the property's value. The pair (hidden class, offset) is then cached for this specific property load, so the next lookup (even in still-unoptimized code) will run quite a bit faster, if another object with the same hidden class comes along next time.

If the function runs hot enough, it will eventually get optimized. The optimizing compiler looks at the hidden classes and offsets that unoptimized code has cached, and assumes that future behavior of your app will be just like past behavior, so it will emit a code sequence like:

1. verify that `obj` has hidden class `hiddenClassA`, otherwise deoptimize
2. load from offset 12

where "deoptimize" means that the entire optimized code for this function will have to be thrown away, because it is apparently based on invalid assumptions, and execution will go back to unoptimized code to collect more type feedback (until a potential later re-optimization with new feedback, if it still runs hot enough). As long as it *doesn't* have to deopt though, the optimized code will be nearly as fast as what C would do for structs, and it won't have to do any property lookups because it just relies on the cached offsets.

This mechanism is also why it wouldn't make sense to compile optimized code right away: things like property accesses can't reasonably be optimized when the optimizing compiler has no cached type information (generated by unoptimized execution) available. Because then the optimizing compiler would ask exactly the same question you did: "how on earth am I supposed to figure out what offset property `a` maps to???"

Answer (score 1):

I think it helps to look at an overly simplified example how an object could look like in memory:

```
 { a: 1, b: 2 }
 // represented as
 address | 0  | 1  | 2  |  3   | 4  | 5  |
 value   | 3  | 1  | 2  |  a   | b  |    |
```

The object value is stored at address 0. The first value 3 points to the "hidden class". To retrieve the value of key "a" of the object at 0, one would read 0, then read the value at the address stored in 0, and then count up and look up that addresses value till we find "a". Luckily it's the first key, so we can then go back to the object, and add the offset 1 to our adress 0, and find the value at 0 + 1. Or in pseudocode (C++):

```
 void* obj = 0;
 void* hidden_class = *obj;
 int offset = 0;
 while(*(hidden_class + offset) != 'a') offset++;
 int value = *(obj + offset + 1);
```

Now if we have another object looking like this:

```
 address | 100  | 101  | 102 |
 value   |   3  |   5  |   7 |
```

Then we could use the same method as above, or if the place were we do `obj.a` always gets objects passed in that are of that hidden class, we could also just do this:

```
  void* obj = 100;
  assert(*obj == 3);
  int value = *(obj + 1);
```

So if an engine sees that objects with the same hidden class get passed to a function, it could compile the function and instead of using the search algorithm in the dictionary, it could directly compile the resulting offset into the function. That doesn't work however if the object passed in is of a different hidden class, and as such the property a might not be at the same offset. Therefore the engine needs to check if the object is of a certain hidden class, and if not, fall back to interpreting / deoptimizing.

The example above is for sure very simplified (not every value fits into one byte).

Comment: "The first value 3 points to the hidden class"

is 3 a pointer then?

Comment: @david_adler yes!

Comment: wasn't familiar with `void *` being the address of untyped memory. would be good if you could add a comment? really helpful though!

Comment: @david well, I can't explain everything in every answer, so I do explain as little as I need so that interested readers can dig in. Great it worked out :)